Super key to open launcher doesn't work on KDE
Can't make KDE app launcher to be open on Super key hit. But others mappings like Super+E (Dolphin) or Super+T (screen layout) works fine.
Already tried the direct solution: to map shortcut to Alt+F1. This one works, but Super no.
Also tried to edit kwinrc with a tip got on reddit:
kwriteconfig5 --file kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Meta "org.kde.kglobalaccel,/component/kwin,org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component,invokeShortcut,Overview"

Neither works.
Got a look on ksuperkey, but this one says that it is for KDE Plasma < 5.8.
One thing that should be noted: This setup is a VM accessed through RDP.
Setup:

Kubuntu: 24.04
KDE Plasma: 5.27.11
Graphics: X11


Edit 1
So, I give a try with ksuperkey and it works now, even for a Plasma version that should not be necessary. Can this be a problem with RDP+X11 combination?

On Plasma 5 there is a bug where the shortcut key for the Application launcher was sometimes "gone" after a reboot. A possible workaround that has worked to me is defining a keyboard shortcut through the panel widget itself. Right click on the launcher icon --> "Configure application launcher" --> "Keyboard shortcuts". Then add the super key as the shortcut and it will be recognized without an additional key.
Or, if you can, update KDE Plasma to 6.

But how to add the super key as shortcut? It doesn't accept it as entry, hitting super alone does nothing.
